# Update Same Store But in Different Component Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My 1 month learn Redux and have some trouble, i have a little e-commerce sample page to make addToCart with Redux, but im not use Pure React To handle all component. in the product page, that list all my Products, i use handle submit to save "Add To Cart" when user click the "Add To Cart" Button, but when user click that, i want my navbar menu that have add to cart icon will update state from my users.

but the problem is, the navbar and Product list is not sync each other, in other word i split the component and render with different DOM, how to update the state from Product list to Navbar but have different Component ?

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
);

if(document.getElementById('product-show')){
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('product-show')
    )
}
```

this is the ProductPage Component which didnt Sync with Cart/Orders Tables in database, but separated with Cart Page, the ProductPage is render inside product-show id.

and the CartPage is same, i copy paste the code and fix the import path.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
);

if (document.getElementById('order-cart')) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('order-cart')
    )
}
```

and this CartPage(or orderPage) is embedded inside Navbar ( Cart Icon ). but store same state from same reducer and action too,

what i want is, when the ProductPage(which have Add to Cart Button to save the order table), the CartPage is update the state too because its store same state, but i must reload the page to update the state from ProductPage

sorry if my english is bad sir, i guess udemy.com separated its component

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: It's hard to help without any code. Please share the important lines. Anyways to make a guess: You can wrap both of your react DOMs into it's own `<Provider>` that provides the store in the context.

Comment: Updated sir, please read again and help me :)

Comment: you are creating a different store for both the instances. However in the first place why are you even trying to use two separate Providers, why not use Route and render different components